# CD burning using ICDBurn

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, msdn

i want to burn my audio files into CD. Is it possible to do programatically.
I heard about ICDBurn. But not gettng that much idea when reading MSDN.
I am from embedded domain.

Can u give some help or sample program.
I want to implement in VC++ or qt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at IMAPI (Image Mastering API) in MSDN.

Comment: Ya i saw that also.. But i think its more complicated than ICDBurn.
My need is to burn CD only.
some body told me implementation of ICD burn taks less time only.

Comment: As for ICDBurn it seems a sample is here (http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c15201) present. The sample is in C#, but I think there will no be dificulties lo learn it.